# glDrawArray is not working

Tags: ios, uiview, opengl-es

I want to make some changes to an image using OpenGL.

So after loading the image, I prepare the texture and I put the following code.But The image didn't change to a triangle.

What am I doing wrong ?

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

static const Vertex3D vertices[] = {
    {-1.0,  1.0, -0.0},
    { 1.0,  1.0, -0.0},
    { 0.0, -1.0, -0.0},

};
static const Vector3D normals[] = {
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
    {0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
};
static const GLfloat texCoords[] = {
    0.0, 1.0,
    1.0, 0.0,
    0.0, 0.0,
};

glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);




glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 3, vertices);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, normals);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoords);
//initiate the drawing process, we want a triangle, start at index 0 and draw 3 vertices

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised by your glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, **3**, vertices); the second 3 indicates the stride (a kind of spacing between the numbers)... I think it should be 0 instead of 3.

glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, **0**, vertices);

Actually, do you see a triangle or nothing at all ?

Good luck!
Pierre

Ok: I tried your code, so I can say :

1) you shall put glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, **0**, vertices); stride of 0 instead of 3, does clearly not work with 3 (even useless to check it) : there is no gap between your values.

2) it may come from your initialisation of the view (common problem): how do you setup the projection and modelview matrices? For instance, to see the triangle, I have to put

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(45.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0); // field of view=45°, zNear..zFar = 1 to 10

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0, 0, -3.0);
```

i.e. don't forget to tell which matrix you wish to set before doing it, and setup the pojection properly: zNear <= min(your vertices.z), zFar >= max(your vertices.z)  (Oooo it is over now, with OpenGL 4, no more implicit matrices)

I wish you find the bug.

Cheers

Comment: Still nothing at all.Here what I did before the that :  
  glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D );                       
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by the  initialisation of the view and the setup the projection and modelview matrices?

Comment: I meant the initialisation of the "OpenGL camera". I can see the 2 lines `glLoadIdentity(); glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -3.0);` but they are not enough to complete the definition of the point of view. Just have a look on [http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/OpenGL:Tutorials:Tutorial_Framework:First_Polygon]